# API Documentation for typescript types for JS libraries

Tags: javascript, express, typescript

I am trying to develop an exrpessjs application in typescript. I installed @types and developed a working application after reading some articles. My question is where do I find documentation for typescript types for the libraries written in javascript.

For example I learned from examples that I need to import Router, Response and Request as follows, I am looking for an official documentation where it lists classes, interfaces that the library exposes through @types

```
import { Router, Response, Request } from 'express';
```

Comment: There usually aren't any. Most of the libraries are written in js. Some of them contain declaration files, but most don't so you need to get those using `@types` or `typings`. The declaration files are the documentation, along with the documentation that the library offers (in their site/github page/etc)

Answer (score 1):

> learned from examples that I need to import Router, Response and Request as follows,

If the JS library is not written in TypeScript it probably has its own docs you should refer to e.g. `Router` is covered here : https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Other than that the usage of definitions can be figured out by autocomplete etc.

## More

In general TypeScript does not solve the problem of poorly documented or bad code. That is left up to the developers (just like any other programming language).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [tsdocs.dev](https://tsdocs.dev).

It builds reference documentation for JS / TS libraries

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).